# Sorting a 3d array using a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 3d 128x28001x8 array which I want to sort using a 128x1 vector. I was wondering whether anyone knows a way to do this?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Can you give us more information? Is the 128x1 vector a vector of indices? Or data that you want to arrange the other matrix by?

Comment: Yes, 128x1 a vector if indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` is your array and `v` is the indices vector, then:

```
sorted_A = A(v,:,:);
```